# Content Search web part on homepage returns an error when logging in

Tags: javascript, caching, sharepoint, web, web-parts

I have a Content Search web part with a dynamic query to my SharePoint lists on homepage.

The page loads correctly when I'm signed in, but fails to load on first login (so I need to refresh the page).

When I'm changing the default homepage, it still works on the first visit.

Here is the error:

> One or more of the following resource files failed to load:
>   /_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/language
>   files/en-US/customstrings.js?ctag=4537$$15.0.4693.1000

P.S. - I checked the JS file above, it really exists. So it looks like a caching issue. Can anyone of SharePoint gurus help me? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by injecting the cached (this is important) script file directly in the page header using a script block:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "/_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/language files/en-US/customstrings.js?ctag=4568$$15.0.4693.1000";
head.appendChild(script);

</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
```